# Canon DSLR without touchscreen for photo enthusiast

Tags: canon

I need to update my Canon 350D to a newer version.

I'm considering models like 700D or 70D.

But what bothers me most is that they all seem to have touchscreen ... which I **hate** (for various reasons I could detail if necessary).

So is it that Canon went all-in with the touch-screen in which case I should probably consider moving to Nikon?

Otherwise, which models are still available to me?

*Subjective comments*:

Shouldn't this decision be left to the user? The fact that the professional models just **don't have a touchscreen** is a proof that it is a **gadget** feature, isn't it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a rant, not a real question.

Comment: The decision *is* up to the user. If the feature is so poorly implemented, people will buy other cameras without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable touch screen control on a 700D or 70D in the menus.

So, frankly, I think your assumption that you have to get a different camera or switch systems because you loathe them and find them to be simply a novelty feature is wrong.

On top of that, I have some cameras without touch screens and one with it, and I find the utility of it (and of that other "novelty" feature, wi-fi) to be supremely useful.  Certainly, AF-point selection is much quicker and easier when you can just tap on a touchscreen.  But personal tastes vary.

Which is why Canon lets you turn off the touchscreen controls if you want.

[addendum]
I also think your assumption that a pro camera not having a feature is proof that that feature is useless for everyone is also incorrect. The 1-series pro Canon dSLRs don't have mode dials.  Do you believe this makes a mode dial a useless feature?  Does it "harm the usability" of your camera to have one?

Comment: I appreciate to read that it can be turned off. I read [somewhere else](http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-EOS-700D-vs-Canon-EOS-750D) that one consequence of having touchscreen was "having less buttons" which let me think some options were touchscreen-accessible-only. I'm not rejecting novelty, but a possible trend of always adding features that at some point harm usability.